# head & tail function in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tail, head

What is the most effective procedure or equivalent for "head" & "tail" in Tableau if you are try to isolate the last or first items of an vector?
The known procedure e.g. in R is easy if you are looking for an average of the last 10 numbers: 
`mean(head(x, 10))` or `mean(tail(x, 10))`.
I try to find a solution in Tableau with LOD "max" & "min" but "show me the first 10 min items"?! No chance!

Comment: First() and Last()??

Comment: I'm looking for the equivalent of ```mean(head(x, 10))```.

```avg(first(x, 10))``` - no, thats no solution.

Comment: Where are these vectors you are talking about? Are you talking about rows in a database table? Tableau queries relational tables where data row order is undefined. Or are you talking about partitions of the query results that you examine with table calcs, such as when you call R from Tableau?

Comment: x is the vector and contains n values - e.g. integers.
With "equivalent" I try to explain that there is for the same task an other wording/syntax in Tableau, Pyrhon, C++ ... 
To find the first 10 numbers from x in R: ```head(x, 10)```, and what is the equivalent for that in Tableau. Ok?
And for the average: ```mean(head(x, 10))```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about table calculations, then you can use the WINDOW_XXX() functions -- such as `window_sum(sum(x), 1, 10)` or `window_avg(sum(x), size()-9, size())`

Table calcs operate on the aggregated query results returned from the data source, hence the aggregation function sum() around the field x.

It might be simpler to learn to use Top N filters instead table calcs, depending on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: What I've found out:

```first()``` is looking for the 10 smalest numbers, not for the "first" number.
If your vector goes like this
```[3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 5, 9, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1]```
the "first - function" count the 10 smallest numbers!, not this row ```[3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 5, 9, 4..]```

The "first()" needs an Index or data to knows what "first" means.

So there is e need for an additional Information e.g. "sagt_date" 

```window_sum(sum(x), first() from [startdate], 10)```.

Comment: First() does not do what you seem to think it does. See the function definitions in the REFERENCE section of the online help. First() simply returns the offset from the current item in a partition set to the beginning of the partition. So if you are at position 1, first() returns 0. If you at position 2, first() returns -1. At position 3, first() returns -2. Index() returns the current position in the partition. Last() returns the offset to reach the last position. Size() returns the number of positions in the partition. All this is impacted by how you choose to partitition and order the data

Comment: P.S. I just edited the example in the first paragraph of my answer now that I better understand what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Thx, Alex. 
Yes I know the "definition" of "first()". 
It's a bit weird ...

Comment: The other thing that might be causing confusion is that the formula you write is only part of what defines how a table calc behaves. You also specify how to partition the results into blocks and what order to traverse each block. The first() function will give different results depending on how you choose to partition the data. The tableau UI tries to simplify this using the term 'compute using' which I think confuses more than clarifies. The online help has a section using the terms partitioning and addressing that is helpful.